# Dynamically access specific object property using variable

Tags: object, properties

I have 2 objects 'data' and 'users' I want to use an object property of data to select a property from the users object. I want to do this

```
sentToId = users. (data.recipient) . id
```

What is the correct syntax?

Many thanks!

Comment: Would be nice to know which programming language do you want to use. I have an idea, but just to be sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a new object

```
 recipientObj = users[data.recipient];
 sentToId = recipientObj.id;
```